# Last line of text cut off when viewing MS Word documents

Tags: ms-office, libreoffice, phpword, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-basic

I am facing last line cut-off issue in when I created a file in Libre Office, but when I open it in word 2013 or 2016 last line content are cut-off in between.

You can understand the problem in more detail.

http://blog.submittable.com/2015/04/last-line-of-text-cut-off-when-viewing-ms-word-documents/

I have search a lot on web for solution but I did not find anything.
Is there any automated way (macros/any add on) by which 
I can  add 3-4 empty enter at the end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Basic code is cobbled together from [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), especially section 5.17.1.

```vb
Sub AddParagraphBreaks
    Dim oCursor As Object
    Dim oText As Object
    Dim iBRKConst As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    oText = ThisComponent.Text
    oCursor = oText.createTextCursor()
    oCursor.gotoEnd(False)
    iBRKConst = com.sun.star.text.ControlCharacter.PARAGRAPH_BREAK
    For i = 1 to 3
        oText.insertControlCharacter(oCursor, iBRKConst, False)
    Next i
End Sub
```